# How to update test step header from REST resource request in soapUI free version?

Tags: soapui

I am new to SoapUI and I have a project with many test cases already scripted. Now i wanted to run my tests against to a new environment where it required session token in header for all the REST requests.

1. Is there a way i can update header in all requests in project (or interface) in one go?
2. how do i get update all the test steps with the header with out updating one by one test case?

Thanks,
Ruwi

i have tried adding header to one rest request (under service interface ), but it wont update the test cases it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Check at the root level where you define your request which contains verbs as well, add a header information there, and you should be able to see it in all the request, as I am able to see, only contention , I am using a paid version not a free version.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you mean interface level where all requests are grouped in ? if so as i mentioned in question i did try it that way and the problem is it wont update test cases i already created. i am using free version where i am struggle to update all tests taking those requests in one go.